# Edit the height and width of slices in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, slices

I was trying to choose the height and width to a slice in Illustrator.

In Photoshop, one can do this by right clicking. How can I do it in Adobe Illustrator?

Answer (score 3):

The same way you can change the bounding dimensions of *any* other object in illustrator. Change the H and W value in the control bar at top and/or transform panel.